# 9patch image with only horizontal scaling

Tags: android, android-image

How do I create a 9Patch image that only scales horizontally? I don't want it to scale vertically. I am not able to create such a 9 PNG.

I tried the article http://radleymarx.com/blog/simple-guide-to-9-patch/ but their method is not working. When I skip the left guide, it gives an error in Eclipse.

I am trying to scale this [image](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7878178/head4.png) horizontally, to create a header bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using a tiled drawable instead of a 9patch:

You create a new drawable via xml, using the non-9patch version of your image, then set the tileMode to repeat. You can then set this new drawable as the background of your header, and it should display as you've described.

http://androidblogger.blogspot.com/2009/01/how-to-have-tiled-background-cont.html

Comment: If I am not wrong, even "repeat" would tile the image both ways. Doesn't it?

Comment: You're right. You can set the layout to have a height matching the size of the image. That would prevent any vertical repeating;

Answer (score 4):

Well, you could mark the vertical scaling as some part of your image which is transparent. May be just near the top and bottom edges. Only those parts would scale vertically. The other vertical section would stay the same.

Comment: Actually, I don't want to scale the image vertically at all. Is that not supported?

Comment: Leaving out the left side marks is not supported. If you can post a sample image and explain how you want it to expand/scale, that would be great.

Comment: You will need to modify the image a little, add a little padding at the top and bottom of the image and make those areas as expandable. As far as I know, you will have to specify the vertical expandable portions while creating a 9 patch. I am assuming that the view that would host this image, is almost the same size of the image. That should take care of the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Even if this Question has been answered a few years ago, I got another solution for myself.
I tried to have some Textviews in a vertical LinearLayout, all with the same with but a variable height ( depending on their content ).

My solution:

```
android:paddingLeft="60dp"
android:paddingRight="60dp"
```

( If you want your Textviews slimmer, than add a higher padding value )

In the LinearLayout:
    android:paddingLeft="60dp"
    android:paddingRight="60dp"

And set its children ( the textviews ):

- the 9patch file as backgroud
- android:layout_width="match_parent"
- android:layout_height="wrap_content"